# Django form input missing in POST data

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using Django 1.9.8 and I'm trying to learn how to use form validation. I'm working on a form for registering users. I have 2 problems that I'm stuck on.

1. The field for re-entering the password isn't accessible (rather, just not there at all) in the forms.py file methods.  When I use `raise Exception(self.cleaned_data.get('password'))` to view the content, the password is shown. I can also view the username and email. When I do the same for the repassword field, it shows `None` **Edit - this was solved by changing the forms.py file to use a clean() method**
2. The validation errors are not displaying at all on my form. If there are errors the redirect back to the form is working, but there is nothing in the inputs for the user to fix, nor is the error displayed. **Edit - solved by changing the RegisterForm call after the else statement to `form = RegisterForm(request.POST)`**

Here is the forms.py file

```
#forms.py
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    email = forms.CharField(label="Email", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password', 'type' : 'password'}))
    repassword = forms.CharField(label="RePassword", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'repassword', 'type' : 'password'}))

    #Edit - this was changed to the clean() function in the selected answer.
    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('repassword')
        #raise Exception(self.cleaned_data.get('repassword')) # None is displayed

        if password1 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Here's the form template

```
#register.html

{% if form.errors %}
    <h2>ERROR!</h2>
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="" id="RegisterForm">
{% csrf_token %}
    <p class="bs-component">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.email.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.email }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>{{ form.repassword.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.repassword }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    <p class="bs-component">
        <center>
            <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="Register" />
        </center>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

Here's the view

```
#views.py
class RegisterViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    #GET requests
    def register(self,request):
        return render(request, 'authorization/register.html', {'form': RegisterForm})

    #POST requests
    def create(self,request):
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/users')
        else:
            return render(request, 'authorization/register.html', {'form': RegisterForm })
            #changed the previous line to the following. This fixed the errors not displaying
            #return render(request, 'authorization/register.html', {'form': RegisterForm(request.POST) })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not %100 sure why `self.cleaned_data.get('repassword')` returns `None` in that method, however `clean_password` is not the right place for performing validations of fields that depend on each other.

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), you should perform that kind of validation in [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.clean) function:

**views.py**

```
def register(self,request):
    form = RegisterForm() # Notice `()` at the end
    return render(request, 'authorization/register.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
...

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegisterForm, self).clean()

    password1 = cleaned_data.get('password')
    password2 = cleaned_data.get('repassword')

    if password1 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
```

Please note that you don't have to implement `clean_password` and `clean_repassword`.

*(If you think you still have to implement `clean_password`, you have to return `password1` from it, not `self.cleaned_data`.)*

You also need to render form errors correctly as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages).

Don't forget to add it in your template:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

As for the second error, the problem is, every time the validation fails you are returning a new fresh `RegisterForm` instance instead of the invalidated one.

You should change the line in `create()` function:

```
return render(request, 'authorization/register.html', {'form': RegisterForm})
```

to this:

```
return render(request, 'authorization/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: The repassword field is now accessible in the forms.py file and validating correctly, but the form is still blank upon redirect, and no errors are being displayed. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you change the related line to `return render(request, 'authorization/register.html', {'form': form})` in the `else` clause? Also you should update your template like how it is explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) here.

Comment: Yes, I even copied and pasted it to be 100% sure there were no spelling errors.

Comment: I did that too. I'll update template above to reflect. Regardless, shouldn't the form inputs have the content filled in? They're empty for me.

Comment: Yes it should have. You are probably doing something that is not shown in your question. You should put a breakpoint to make sure you hit the `else` clause when `form.is_valid()` returns false.

Comment: I added an exception as soon as the else is hit, and it was triggered. I at least know it's making it to the else.

Comment: Okay it was triggered and then what happens? Are you sure you are not calling `register()` view somewhere else afterwards? No redirection should take place if form couldn't be validated. Can you also print `form.as_table()` in the `else` block to see user-entered inputs are there?

Comment: Got it to work by changing the RegisterForm call to `form = RegisterForm(request.POST)`